# Silverstripe publish page in the future

Tags: php, module, cron, backend, silverstripe

I'm trying to make a schedule publish module (publish a simple page at some date in the future).
I searched for a similar plugin and found Embargo-Expiry Module which also includes Queued Jobs module. I've installed and configured them both successfully as dev-master, but don't know how to configure or use them. i got only a tab in the admin area which looks like this:
[image]

So do i need any cron jobs for this ? how can i do it? I just want a new button near publish , like wordpress, set the publish/unpublish date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is more simple solution:

1. Add PublishDate field to your page class
2. Set the publish date in the future and publish the page.
3. Handle the page visibility in the index() method of page controller. Return 404 HTTP error if page is not published when the page is requested.

For example add /mysite/code/FuturePublishDate.php

```
<?php

class FuturePublishDate extends DataExtension
{
    private static $db = array(
        'PublishDate' => 'SS_DateTime'
    );

    public function updateCMSFields(FieldList $fields) {
        $datetimeField = new DatetimeField( 'PublishDate', 'Publish From' );

        $dateField = $datetimeField->getDateField();
        $dateField->setConfig( 'dateformat', 'yyyy-MM-dd' );
        $dateField->setConfig( 'showcalendar', true );

        $timeField = $datetimeField->getTimeField();
        $timeField->setConfig( 'timeformat', 'H:m:s' );

        $fields->insertBefore( $datetimeField, 'Content' );
    }

    public function populateDefaults() {
        $this->owner->PublishDate = SS_Datetime::now();
    }
}

class FuturePublishDateController extends Extension
{
    public function beforeCallActionHandler($request, $action) {
        if ('index' !== $action || $this->owner->is_a('ErrorPage_Controller')) {
            return;
        }

        $isDraftPreview = 'Stage' === $request->getVar('stage');

        if( !$isDraftPreview 
            && $this->owner->PublishDate
            && strtotime($this->owner->PublishDate) > strtotime('now')
        ){
            // bug in SS 3.1 in OldPageRedirector
            // $this->owner->httpError( 404 );

            $response = $request->isMedia() ? null : ErrorPage::response_for(404);
            if ($response) {
                return $response;
            }

            throw new SS_HTTPResponse_Exception('404 Not Found', 404);
        }
    }
}
```

and register in mysite/_config/config.yml

```
---
Name: mysiteconfig
---
Page:
  extensions:
    - FuturePublishDate
Page_Controller:
  extensions:
    - FuturePublishDateController
```

Define default action in Page.php for hook beforeCallActionHandler to work

```
class Page_Controller extends ContentController
{
    public function index(SS_HTTPRequest $request) {
        return $this->getViewer('index')->process($this);
    }

    public function Menu($level) {
        $items = parent::Menu($level);

        $isDraftPreview = 'Stage' === $this->request->getVar('stage');
        if ($isDraftPreview) {
            return $items;
        }

        $now = strtotime('now');
        $visible = array();
        foreach ($items as $page) {
            if ($page->PublishDate && strtotime($page->PublishDate) <= $now) {
                $visible[] = $page;
            } elseif (!$page->PublishDate) {
                $visible[] = $page;
            }
        }

        return new ArrayList($visible);
    }
}
```

If you use SilverStripe 3.3.1, you need to delete a line in Controller.php

```
protected function handleAction($request, $action) {
    //DELETED $this->extend('beforeCallActionHandler', $request, $action);

    foreach($request->latestParams() as $k => $v) {
```

And run `dev/build?flush=1`

Comment: first, thanks for help. I tried this code but i'm afraid no success. After dev/build, everythings was ok, the field shown in the CMS, choose a future date(few minutes in the future) and then saved as a draft. The page appeared instantly (before the choosen date) . i read again and you said 'publish' so i created a new page, choose a new future date, and i published it. the page wasn't visible, and when the time to publish was reached, still not shown...waited few minutes, keep refreshing, flushed the cash and still not visible. Any ideas ? Thanks again

Comment: right :) beforCallActionHandler is not called for implicit default action `index`. You have to define it in Page.php

Comment: thanks for edits. i made the changes but now, when i create a new page(before publishing or saving as draft) the page is automaticaly published as a new page on website and when i hit publish or save as draft,  the page just updates the name i gave in the CMS, so still no success :(

Comment: @Spidey What version of SS framework do you use? You observe standard behaviour. When new page is created, it is automatically saved as draft with name 'New {page ClassName}', so by default it is 'New Page'. Nothing is published at this point. If you observer different behaviour at this stage, most probably you have some other code / extension that modifies behaviour. I checked my answer code with SS 3.3.1

Comment: i am using 3.1.18, a fresh installer with no other extensions that could affect the behaviour. Just hit the create new page inside CMS and the draft "New Page" is published in my case before any other changes. i'm not sure if it's becouse of the CMS version, becouse i don't have any other errors. Anyway, appreciate your work and answer, but if i don't ask you yoo much, share for me and those in the same situation a different way (if you know ofcourse). That module Embargo and Expiry i think make exactly what i need, but i don't know how to integrate it with cron jobs and configure them. Thanks

Comment: I tried with 3.1.18, fresh install, and the changes above. All works as expected. New page is added to draft stage only. If I change the page and click 'Save' button only. All changes are applied and remain in draft stage.

Comment: you ware right. Draft shows becouse i was logged in. Tried in incognito, and the draft is hidden when added from CMS. The problem is now the showing in Menu. I mean, when i publish the page in a future time, the page content is hidden(404 not found) until the chosen datetime is reached, but it is shown in the Frontend Menu immediatly, before the datetime is reached. So i think, a condition is required for the Page not to be displayed even in Menu until the right time. Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately you cannot handle Menu with extension, but we can overload ContentController::Menu() in Page_Controller::Menu() to filter future articles. See updated code.

Comment: thanks for complete answer. also, that Menu hook needs $request object. i made it as follow:   $request = new SS_HTTPRequest;

Comment: No, this is incorrect. The proper request object is stored on the controller instance. You can get it with `$this->request` or `$this->getRequest()`.

Answer (score 4):

From the documentation of https://github.com/silverstripe-scienceninjas/embargoexpiry...

```
Ensure the QueuedJobs module is installed and configured correctly. You should have a cronjob similar to the following in place, running as the webserver user.

*/1 * * * * cd  && sudo -u www php /sites/default/www/framework/cli-script.php dev/tasks/ProcessJobQueueTask
```

Note: you'll need to update the path to cli-script.php to reference your own environment.
There are also many more examples on the queuedjobs module itself https://github.com/nyeholt/silverstripe-queuedjobs

Comment: Anyway, i'm new to silverstripe and cron job, so i don't know how to make it. tried to execute this comment (also updated the path), but got an error */ not folder found. If you can be a bit more explicit would be great. Thanks

Comment: type "crontab -e" at the command prompt to edit your cron jobs

Comment: i did, then i typed: crontab -l, and i got the same line i've entered before: */1 * * * * cd  && sudo -u www php /public_html/framework/cli-script.php dev/tasks/ProcessJobQueueTask    . I have also ran http://url/dev/tasks/ProcessJobQueueTask and i got: Running Task ProcessJobQueueTask

[2016-03-10 13:01:17] Processing queue 2 [2016-03-10 13:01:17] No new jobs .     But the Jobs tab is still empty in the CMS and i have no options from embargo or expiry to schedule the publishing date. Any ideas ?

Comment: if you know how to do it, can you share for those who need a more detailed step by step solution ? thank you